# How to derive a new column in Python when importing csv into postgres

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have a huge dataset (11GB, 19million rows) and am loading it into postgres using the following script:

```html
import csv
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float, Boolean
class Complaint(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'all_complaints'

    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_date = Column(DateTime)
    closed_date = Column(DateTime)
    complaint_type = Column(String)
    descriptor = Column(String)
    location_type = Column(String)
    incident_zip = Column(Integer)
    incident_address = Column(String)
    address_type = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    borough = Column(String)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    bedbug = Column(Boolean)
    water = Column(Boolean)
    noise = Column(Boolean)
    heat = Column(Boolean)
    pests = Column(Boolean)

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User(index='%s', created_date='%s', incident_zip='%s')>" % (
                            self.index, self.created_date, self.incident_zip)
    def addZip(self, zip):  #some zips are string in the csv file
        try:
            self.incident_zip = int(zip)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            #print("Could not parse zip code", zip)
            return False

dbname = ''
username = ''
engine = create_engine('postgres://%s@localhost/%s'%(username,dbname), echo=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


with open("311_Service_Requests_from_2010_to_Present.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        complaint = Complaint(index = i,
                              created_date = row['Created Date'],
                              closed_date = row['Closed Date'],
                              complaint_type = row['Complaint Type'],
                              descriptor = row['Descriptor'],
                              location_type = row['Location Type'],
                              incident_address = row['Incident Address'],
                              address_type = row['Address Type'],
                              city = row['City'],
                              borough = row['Borough'],
                              latitude = row['Latitude'],
                              longitude = row['Longitude'],
                              bedbug = False,
                              water = False,
                              noise = False,
                              heat = False,
                              pests = False)
                              #more fields here, everything you can copy exactly
        addedZipSuccessfully = complaint.addZip(row['Incident Zip'])
        if addedZipSuccessfully == False:
            continue
        if complaint.created_date == '':
            #complaint.created_date = NULL
            continue
        if complaint.closed_date == '':
            complaint.closed_date = None
        if complaint.location_type == '':
            continue
        if complaint.incident_address == '':
            continue
        if complaint.address_type == '':
            continue
        if complaint.city == '':
            continue
        if complaint.borough == '':
            continue
        try:
            float(complaint.latitude)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        try:
            float(complaint.latitude)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if 'Noise' in complaint.complaint_type == True:
            complaint.noise = True
        else:
            pass
        session.add(complaint)

        if i % 1000 == 0:
            session.commit()
```

I got the columns I want from my csv into the database using this code, but now I want to update my 'noise' column (and eventually bedbug, water, heat, and pests) to be true if the complaint_type column contains 'Noise' in the string.

I've tried:

```html
            if 'Noise' in complaint.complaint_type == True:
                complaint.noise = True
```

which doesn't update any of the fields (which evaluate to true when I check the string externally. Any ideas of how to code this in Python3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "== True" confuses Python3. Remove it and it will work like you intend to.

```
if 'Noise' in complaint.complaint_type:
    complaint.noise = True
```